# How to properly use touchmove using React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch-event

I am trying to build a draggable slider for mobile users only. Because of that, I chose to use the touch events but I have some problems.

The `touchmove` event doesn't seem to work at all. I have a `touchstart` event that calculates the `offsetX` of the elements from the slide and the `offsetLeft` position of the track. I should mention that the event is on the container of the slider. Inside the function, for the `touchstart` event I added the `touchmove` and `touchend` events and passed the constants as arguments to `touchmove` event. When consol log-ing the constants they seems to work fine, but when doing the calculation the slider doesn't move.

This is the part of the code with the touch events:

PS: there are other effects built into this component but they shouldn't affect the touch event. Hopefully. I will also leave a link to a git repro with the entire code if it helps. : https://github.com/CodyHiII/files/tree/main/Navigation

```
  const [isPressedDown, setIsPressedDown] = useState(false);
  const [touchMoveDistance, setTouchMoveDistance] = useState(0);
```

```
  const touchEvent = touchMoveDistance;
  console.log(touchEvent);
  const mouseHoverEvent = mouseOut ? -mouseX / navScrollSpeed + navScrollOffset
    : 0;
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
    navContainerRef.current.addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
  }, []);

  const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
    setIsPressedDown(true);
    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const offsetX = e.touches[0].clientX - window.pageXOffset - rect.left;
    const offsetLeft = navTrackRef.current.offsetLeft;
    const cursorXPoss = offsetX - offsetLeft;

    navContainerRef.current.addEventListener(
      "touchmove",
      handleTouchMove(e, offsetX, cursorXPoss)
    );
    navContainerRef.current.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = useCallback(() => {
    setIsPressedDown(false);
  }, []);

  const handleTouchMove = (e, offsetX, cursorXPoss) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTouchMoveDistance(offsetX - cursorXPoss);
  };
```

```
        <div
          style={{
            left: `${isPressedDown ? touchEvent : mouseHoverEvent}px`,
          }}
          className={styles.navTrack}
          ref={navTrackRef}
        >
          {data.map((link, index) => (
            <div
              key={`${link.title} ${index}`}
              className={styles.navLink}
              onClick={() => handleNavLinks()}
            >
              <a href={link.path}>
                <div className={styles.linkCardContainer}>
                  <h4 className={styles.linkCardTitle}>{link.title}</h4>
                  <div className={styles.linkCardImg}></div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you happen to be using the Firefox browsers dev tools' touch simulation when you experience the problems? If that is the case, I registered a bug back in Jan 2022  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1752813

Comment: i use the chrome dev tools

Comment: Have you tested it on an actual touch device such as mobile or tablet? You may find that things work differently outside of dev tools as they are actually simulating touch devices and are not a substitute for them. Useful yes, but 100% reflective of the actual response of a touch device, no!

Comment: Yes, the problem is from the code, I just logged the touchMoveDistance which is the hook that is supposed to change the left position of the track and it's logging in with 0. Can't figure out what is the problem tho... Also, I tested it on Mozilla and it's true, it uses the mouse input instead of the touch.